# Get all div's that doesn't have an id

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

What is the most **efficent** way of getting all the divs on the page that doesn't have an id with using jquery or just vanilla js if its more efficient. I know that I can get all divs and loop through them and check if they have set ids. I am just curious if DOM API or Jquery has an optimized way of doing this.

Comment: $('div') gets all divs? or do you mean you want all divs where it doesn't have an id

Comment: document.querySelectorAll('div:not([id])')

Comment: think its specifically '*without* an id'

Comment: yes, but I want to get all divs without an id

Comment: Two methods can both be the most efficient depending on circumstances. In most cases, it's best to just do something then go back and make it more efficient if there's a problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just do (jQuery):

```
var divs = $("div:not([id])");
```

Or, as nicely pointed out by @PitaJ

```
document.querySelectorAll('div:not([id])')
```

Comment: Or with the new querySelectorAll, `document.querySelectorAll('div:not([id])')`

Comment: @PitaJ -- Thanks, added that to the answer (and credit, of course)

Comment: Does this document.querySelectorAll('div:not([id])') slow down the browser than just doing document.querySelectorAll('div'), depending on the DOM size and how many divs there are, can doing document.querySelectorAll('div') and looping them manually ever be faster?

Comment: @GorkemYurtseven - looks like the manual way is faster: jsperf.com/manual-or-with-not

Comment: Also, $("div").not("[id]") may be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Using Not : http://api.jquery.com/not/
eg :

```
$("div:not('#id'))
```

or:

```
$("div").not('#id');
```

Answer (score -2):

With jquery you would do

```
var divs = $('div:not([id])');
```

That will give you reference to all the divs present in the page

With vanilla js you would do

```
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div:not([id])');
```